# Adding numeric vectors of unequal length in a list together with an offset based on the index?

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors as given by:

`list_num <- list(c(1,1,1,1,1), c(2,2), c(5), c(3,3,3,3,3))`

I want to add all these vectors together, but offset each vector by the value of it's position in the list. i.e.- when adding the second vector c(2,2), we add it to the second position onwards to the first. So essentially, it'd look like the following, where all the elements are added up together

```
list_num <- list(c(1,1,1,1,1), c(0,2,2), c(0,0,5), c(0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3))

# Output:
>> 1 3 8 4 4 3 3 3
```

My current approach involves generating a vector to house the added results and iterating over each element to add it in:

```
# Find the length for each of the vectors in the list
list_len <- unlist(lapply(list_num, function(x) { return(length(x))}))

# Find how long will the vector to add the results have to be
list_len <- 1:length(list_num)+list_len

# Generate a vector to house the added results
list_len <- rep(0, max(list_len)-1) 

# Then iterate over each of the elements by index i 
for(i in 1:length(list_num)){

  # Add the vector at position i to the subset of our aggregated vector
  list_len[i:(i+length(list_num[[i]])-1)] <- list_len[i:(i+length(list_num[[i]])-1)] + list_num[[i]]
}

print(list_len)
>> 1 3 8 4 4 3 3 3
```

But I think this is rather inefficient; I'm looking for a more efficient way to go about aggregating these vectors.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` to add offset 0's using `rep`

```
out <- lapply(seq_along(list_num), function(n) c(rep(0, n-1), list_num[[n]]))
out

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 0 2 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 0 0 5

#[[4]]
#[1] 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3
```

We can then add `NA`'s to make length equal and calculate row-wise sum.

```
rowSums(sapply(out, `[`, 1:max(lengths(out))), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1 3 8 4 4 3 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a step in the right direction- but it doesn't include how to add them up together which would still require iterating over each element.

Comment: I missed that part. I have updated the answer to include that.

Comment: Thanks for doing so! I ran a couple of tests though, and while much more concise than my current solution, it appears to be much slower, possibly from adding the leading zeroes (I meant to include that step to illustrate what the calculation would look like).

Answer (score 0):

The requirement does not seem very hard to code in C++, hence here is an option using `Rcpp`:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("NumericVector psumUnevenList(List a, int len) {
    NumericVector res(len), v;

    for (int i=0; i<a.length(); i++) {
        v = a[i];
        for (int j=0; j<v.length(); j++) {
            res[i+j] += v[j];
        }
    }

    return res;
}")
maxn <- max(seq_along(list_num) - 1L + lengths(list_num))
psumUnevenList(list_num, maxn)
#[1] 1 3 8 4 4 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution (two-steps):

```
# Store a scalar valued at the length of longest vector in the list: 
vec_list_max_length <- max(lengths(vec_list))

# Set the length of each vector to be equal to the maximum length, rowbind the list
# together and get the sum of each row: 
rowSums(sapply(vec_list, function(x) {
  length(x) = vec_list_max_length
  return(replace(x, is.na(x), 0))
}))
```

Data:

```
vec_list <- list(c(1,1,1,1,1), c(0,2,2), c(0,0,5), c(0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3))
```